# Importing a .json model from Blender into three.js breaks the model

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

When I import a .json model from Blender into three.js, the model does not look as it should be. It looks broken.
Here the code I used for loading my model:

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load('models/SideMattress.js', addModelToScene);
```

And this how I add it to the scene:

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var map = textureLoader.load( "textures/SideMattress-TM.jpg");
var displacementMap = textureLoader.load("textures/SideMattress-DM.jpg");
var normalMap = textureLoader.load( "textures/SideMattress-NM.jpg" );

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
     map: map,
     normalMap: normalMap,
     displacementMap: displacementMap,
});

sideMattress = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
sideMattress.position.y = 1.7;   //set the y position
scene.add(sideMattress);
```

I'm attaching the JSON file from Blender exporter as a screen shot since its very long...

[JSON File from Blender Exporter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBGjU.png)

I'm not sure if the problem is with the exporter or the way I use the mesh materials, or the model itself. Here is the result I get in my browser before and after texture mapping.

[The model before & after adding texture mapping inside Three.js and how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ohsJ.png)

Note that when I also add the displacement map, it has no effect which is not how it is supposed to.

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: In what way is it broken?

Comment: I have edited my post such that the second figure shows how it is rendered outside three.js to show you how it should look like. Thx

Comment: Looks like the normals are backwards? Also, the normal map texture (the purplish one) looks flipped compared to the other textures.

Comment: Actually it is a mistake in the uploaded image only. I've corrected that thx for ur observation. But my texture mapping problem is still there :(